# Firestore Increment FieldValue

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

So, I know there are a few similarly named questions, but this is not the same.
I am curious to see if anyone could explain the reasoning for the lack of an `increment` sentinel, similar to the `delete` one.

As far as I know, a field deletion is no different than a document update. Meaning, I can just `delete` my field by simply updating the entire document to some new data, leaving that field out, hence, the question.

If we have a `FieldValue.delete()`, why the lack of a `FieldValue.increment()`

Note: I am aware of the 1QPS limit and I doubt it has anything to do with the above.

Regards!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Version 5.9.0 - Mar 14, 2019**
>
> Added FieldValue.increment(), which can be used in update() and
>   set(..., {merge:true}) to increment or decrement numeric field values
>   safely without transactions.

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js

Comment: Perfect :) Thank you so much!

Comment: Is this currently working in cloud functions? When I try to use it the value is never incremented.

Comment: @ajaxon You can access that in functions from the firestore static property admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)

Comment: @HamishJohnson this doesn't seem to work for nested object properties. is it supposed to?

Comment: @Crashalot I haven't tested but yes it should