# Firestore increment int value if it is exist with flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

hi guys  i am trying to develop an  app but i need  some help i have a function i just need to do if item is exist on firestore i need  to increment "quantity" value of it. i already got and printing the value but i need  some help for checker and incrementing value thanks

```
String checker = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('cart')
        .document('LIihBLtbfuJ8Dy640DPd')
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot ds) => ds.data[foodItem.name]);
    if (checker == foodItem.name) {
      await Firestore.instance
          .collection('cart')
          .document('LIihBLtbfuJ8Dy640DPd')
          .get()
          .then((DocumentSnapshot ds) =>
              a = ds.data[foodItem.name]['quantity']);

      Firestore.instance
          .collection("cart")
          .document("LIihBLtbfuJ8Dy640DPd")
          .updateData({
        foodItem.name: {'quantity': q++}
      });
    } else {
      Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction transaction) async {
        await transaction.update(
            Firestore.instance
                .collection("cart")
                .document("LIihBLtbfuJ8Dy640DPd"),
            {
              foodItem.name: {
                'itemName': foodItem.name,
                'imgUrl': foodItem.imageAssetPath,
                'itemPrice': foodItem.price,
                'quantity': q,
              }
            });
      });
    }
```

[image]
this is picture of my firestore as  you can see there is nested nodes there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore Increment FieldValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54543067/firestore-increment-fieldvalue)

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want to increment a value if the field doesn't exist firebase will create it with the value of 1. I am confused as to the checker part of your question.

```
Firestore.instance.collection("cart")
.document("LIihBLtbfuJ8Dy640DPd")
.setData({foodItem.name: {"quantity": FieldValue.increment(1)}});
```

Comment: Likely that needs to be: `updateData({ 'foodItem.name.quantity': FieldValue.increment(1) }).`

Comment: it does not work too because it is nested nodes by the way

Comment: okay I copy and pasted your code ```FieldValue.increment(1)``` works I tried it in my app

Comment: it works but it is outside of the nodes  creating new data

Comment: it is not exactly changing my value it does not effect it

Comment: I see whats happening it's because its nested its showing up on the same level as item right

Comment: as long as your code was writing to firebase correctly before you should be able to take your original code and just replace ```q++``` with ```FieldValue.increment(1)```